# How to flat a nested JSON structure

Tags: json, swift, decoding

**The nested JSON**

```
{
    "items": [{
        "track": {
            "name": "Never Gonna Give You Up"
        }
    }]
}
```

**I want it to look to like this**

```
{
    "tracks": [{
        "name": "Never Gonna Give You Up"
    }]
}
```

**What I've tried**

```
  struct TrackResponse: Decodable {
    let tracks: [Track]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case tracks = "items"
    }

    enum TrackKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case track
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let outerContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      let trackContainer = try outerContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: TrackKeys.self,
                                                              forKey: .tracks)

      self.tracks = try trackContainer.decode([Track].self, forKey: .track)
    }

    struct Track: Decodable {
      var name: String
    }
  }
```

**I'm getting this error**

> Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.

### Update

I created a new question with a bit more context and some changes and ended up reaching my goal by following @vadian's response.

*Check that out and see if it can help you too:*  [Decoding JSON structures with minor differences into just one format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350655/decoding-json-structures-with-minor-differences-into-just-one-format)

Answer (score 0):

Nested containers add a certain degree of complexity to your code, which you can be avoided by using plain old decodables.

Thus, simply declare a (private) struct `Item`, decode it in the intializer of `TrackResponse`, and extract the tracks from there:

```swift
struct TrackResponse: Decodable {
    var tracks: [Track]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let items = try container.decode([Item].self, forKey: .items)
        tracks = items.map(\.track)
    }
    
    struct Track: Decodable {
        var name: String
    }
    
    private struct Item: Decodable {
        var track: Track
    }
}
```

My point here is that you should try to mimic as much as possible the JSON structure, this will make it easier to cope with future changes on the JSON structure. And if you need to represent the data in another form, post-process it after the decoding succeeds.

Myself, I'd go even further and simplify the whole response code:

```swift
struct TrackResponse: Decodable {
    var items: [Item]
    
    struct Track: Decodable {
        var name: String
    }
    
    struct Item: Decodable {
        var track: Track
    }
}
```

, and then simply extract the tracks once the response is received:

```swift
let tracks = response.items.map(\.track)
```

The less code you write, the smaller chances are you introduce bugs ;)

Comment: I was using exactly the structures that you pointed out. However, because I need to make API calls to different endpoints, I was trying to combine three decoding process that resulted in 'Track' into just one function to reduce code duplication. Do you think I can achieve what I wan't without the code duplication?

Comment: To make it clearer, the three calls structures are: response.value.tracks[trackIndex].name , response.value.items[trackIndex].name and response.value.items[trackIndex].track.name . I've managed to parse two of them using just one method, the third is the one I've mentioned in the question.

Comment: @GabrielD.Mendes not sure what you mean, it depends on how those 3 API's look like, and which responses they send.

Comment: Do you want me to send you the full code from this section so you can take a look? It's quite small

Comment: @GabrielD.Mendes you might want to ask a new question instead, clarifying these aspects, since it seems your goal if quite different of the one stated in the current question. Or, you can edit the current question, if the extra details don't alter it too much

Comment: Ok, thanks anyways. I will alter this question, take a look if you can

Comment: @GabrielDM on second thought, better to ask a new question, as the edit will likely invalidate the existing answers, and that's not nice :)

Comment: Tried to make it in a way that doesn't invalidate the two answers. If you think I changed the topic by too much, I'll edit it again to the prior question and create a new question for that topic

Comment: @GabrielDM yeah, that's a whole different question, the new goal is to join three JSON formats under the same struct, while the original text was asking only about the flattening of one of those response.

Comment: @GabrielDM recommending to also add details on how you call those API's, since this might impact the way the potential solutions.

Comment: Thanks again for you attention. I've posted a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350655/decoding-json-structures-with-minor-differences-into-just-one-format). Sorry that I can't give you an upvote because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @GabrielDM will take a look, and I find a solution, will post an answer. Meanwhile others can also do the same, hopefully you'll get a solution soon.